# Send email based on lookup field select

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I have lookup(Personnel Type) field in my big custom list. Which is refer to  Account Request Personnel Type list.

My requirement is :

When users select "Temporary Staff" from Personnel Type lookup field, It will Send email to Manager. Otherwise, If select others, It will send email to HR Approver.

NB:

Account request Personnel Type list contains the following items under Title field.

-Temporary staff

-Permanent staff

-Intern staff

-Field Staff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve it by workflow.

And set the start options as “Allow this workflow to be manually started” and “Start workflow automatically when an item is changed.”.

Then it will trigger the workflow when the item is edited.

And in the workflow, if the Personnel Type is equal to “Temporary Staff”, then send email to Manager. If select others, send email to HR Approver. 
After you add condition “if any value equals value”, you should add “Else Branch”.

[image]

And we should store the value of the lookup column “Personnel Type” in the workflow variable.

The whole workflow as below:

[image]